# Git clone in opt folder

Tags: ubuntu, git-clone

I am trying to download a clone in a specific directory in Ubuntu but after running the following command I can't find the downloaded file in the selected directory. I mean the ThirdPart-5.x can't be found in OpenFOAM folder. could you please let me know what is my mistake?. Many thanks.

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-5.x.git /OpenFOAM
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you view /OpenFOAM?

I guess you tried to view as a non root user and don't have permission to view the directory what you create to clone the repository in root directory.

Try `sudo ls -al /OpenFOAM`.

Comment: I just open the OpenFOAM folder and I didn't find the Thirdparty folder. I need to see the folder and make some changes